# Expired Digital Certificate for an EXE

Tags: certificates, code-signing

An EXE file that I downloaded from the official website has an expired digital certificate signature (1999 to 2015) That is it has been expired for two years. Is it still safe to run the EXE? There is a MD5 hash given below it.

## Edit 1: Link to EXE

This is the EXE that I have downloaded. I need a UNICODE converter. http://downloads.sil.org/EncodingConverters/SEC%204.0%20Web/SEC_PackageOnly.exe Can any of you tell me if it is safe?

## Edit 2: Link to VT

https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/285ca603875e0d109d8e430834e96a2a58d14847e43fb97d5d1a9979cf58ad8f/analysis/1501290577/

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "safe"? And do you think it is "safe" to run any arbitrary executable just because the developer invested some money to get a certificate to sign this executable? A signature says nothing about the intend nor the quality (i.e. amount of vulnerabilities) of the signed software.

Comment: the cert doesn't have anything to do with the safety of the app. period.

Answer (score 1):

Inconclusive. Without any additional information we can't tell you it is a safe application or not. You take a risk running any executable even if it is signed code. This is because anyone can pay for a certificate for their application. And if the issuer revokes it they can just go to another issuer and put out another release. The job of the signature/cert signifies that a developer has released their application as they intended. It does not mean a third party has deemed the file safe and malware free. It is ultimately up to you if you trust that developer or not to run it.